# Store random encryption secret in Android 4.1 (API 16)

Tags: android, encryption, secret-key

I'm building an API-16 application for Android, and I need to store a per-device randomly generated string to use as a symmetric encryption key.

This key will, in turn, encrypt other values that can be kept in preferences or file-system storage.

The KeyStore API is not available on this API level. How can I store this secret, so that it's not recoverable by other applications, or by external access to the device?

Comment: AFAIK, if you hard-code it in the app, it'll be vulnerable to APK decompiling, however, DexGuard](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/dexguard) is said to encrypt `Strings` but I haven't tested it and it's not free. If you generate it on runtime, I couldn't tell if there is a safe place to save it, since once the phone is rooted all data is accesible. The only thing I could think of is saving it in a SQLite database and encrypting it with [SQLCipher](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/), but again, untested and can't provide details on how it works, neithet if they work in that API version.

Comment: You seem to know how to safely do it in newer versions, and I actually need that information. I would really appreciate if you could edit your post and comment a bit on it. I can also create a Question (tomorrow) if you preffer so.